# How can I validate instance field values?

Tags: java, forms, validation

How would I make sure these fields are not left blank when filled in by the user? This is a class file, the info filled in will be called by another main file. I want to make sure the information is filled in but not till everything else is complied at the end (other class files im working on). If the name is left blank then I want the program to state that the name field was left blank and needs to be filled in before i can click on the finish button. any and all help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fillInfo
{
public String name;
public String address;
public String telephone;
public void readInput()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the customers name?");
    name = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the customers telephone number?");
    telephone = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the customers address?");
    address = keyboard.nextLine();
}
public void writeOutput()
{
System.out.println("Sold to: "+ name);
System.out.println("Telephone: "+ telephone);
System.out.println("Address: "+ address);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to mix console and GUI?

Comment: nope not at all. simple program, I am working on. I just need to make sure the fields are entered entirely before the program is done and ends.

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you did something like:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is the customers name?");
name = keyboard.nextLine();
while(name="")//empty string (nothing) entered
{
System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
name = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

.
.
.

Comment: But using a proper compare, not assignment?

Comment: Close, but you need to use .equals(), not == (or =), and you need to check for null as well, meaning EOF.

Comment: ill try this and see if it works. but it look like this is as soon as the field is skipped where as I need the program to let me know that there is an empty field after all of the over information (on other class files) has been entered.

Comment: @user1757726 Isn't it pretty easy to check if an instance value is null or blank? I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @DaveNewton I dont understand "proper compare, not assignment" I am a newbie and need explaining to like I am a 10 year old learning a new language. thank you.

Comment: @user1757726 That comment was directed at the author of this answer.

Comment: nextLine() doesn't return null on EOF.

Comment: @fgb how would i accomplish making the file return null on EOF?

Comment: Isn't it pretty easy to check if an instance value is null or blank? I don't see what the issue is. – Dave Newton...yeah i agree Dave, if you just need to check if any of them are blank at the end can you not just do something like this after all the details have been entered:     if(name=""||telephone=""||address=""){//ask for all details again or could set a flag for each of the details, and depending on which one was set, ask for that detail again}

Answer (score 0):

For each field variable, you could do:

```
while (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
   System.out.println("What is the customers name?");
   name = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

**Update:** It is possible to check the values just before the end of the program and call a helper method like this:

```
if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
   name = getInputValue("What is the customers name?");
}
```

with the corresponding helper method:

```
private String getInputValue(String prompt) {
   System.out.println(prompt);
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   return keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

**Note:** This is is less efficient on resources than the first approach as a new `Scanner` instance is created per missing field variable.

Comment: works, but it works as soon as the information is not entered. i need to program to check when all other information (other class files) has been entered towards the close of the program. if a field is left blank the program will tell you to fill in the missing field.